# Convert UNIX timestamp to date string with format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, json, api, date, weather

I'm trying to print whether it's going to rain or not for given date (mostly next day) in terminal. For that I already get OpenWeatherMap from rapidapi.com.

I convert my response to json

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
obj = response.text
x = json.loads(obj)
print(x['list'][0])
#part of output
{'dt': 1606676400, 'sunrise': 1606662312, 'sunset': 1606697500,
```

and i think the dt is some kind of time, i want to convert it to date in format YYYY-MM-DD, but don't know how.

Thanks for all help, and have a nice day!

Comment: What does the documentation of this API say about the format of these timestamps?

Comment: I guess its a unix timestamp

Comment: Those are epoch times

Answer (score 4):

The format is a `UNIX timestamp`, by the way a very good way of sharing dates, because no extensive parsing is required and datetime library offers an easy way of parsing it

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1606662312
dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

[1] 29.11.2020 16:05
```

EDIT:
If you then need the date in a particular string format you can use:

```
date_string = dt_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
[2] '2020-11-29'
```

For the interested reader:

UNIX timestamp

```
It's pretty common to store date and time as a timestamp in a database. 
A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds between a particular date and 
January 1, 1970 at UTC.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think to get the format what the OP is asking for is to use `strftime` like that `dt_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: Thanks a lot @YasserKhalil I overread that part. I added your answer

Comment: The `str ( ... )` by itself can be used to truncate the time.

Comment: I agree, but ```strftime``` is more general, allowing for different formats as often required for e.g. european countries, plus ```str``` would incloude hours and seconds in case of datetime

Comment: Thank you very much for such explanation!

Comment: @Voquu sure, you are welcome! If it answers your question, I would be greatful if you accepted it :) Cheers and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Given the output of `YYYY-MM-DD` in the question, here is an alternative (without the time) -

```
from datetime import date
dt = 1606676400
dt_convert = date.fromtimestamp(dt)
```

Run from the interpreter -

```
>>> dt_convert
datetime.date(2020, 11, 29)
>>> str(dt_convert)
'2020-11-29'
```